# Fail2ban-regex isn't working

Tags: python, regex, fail2ban

I am trying to check the config on one of my filter jails but every time I run `fail2ban-regex /path/to/log.log /path/to/filter.conf` I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 68, in <module>
    import os
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 400, in <module>
    import UserDict
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 83, in <module>
    import _abcoll
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 11, in <module>
    from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
```

Comment: @MátéJuhász you mean at the end of the command?

Comment: Ended up with the same error

Comment: Is there any _space_ or _not usual_ character in the `/path/to` strings? Maybe you can quote them.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Everything after "Traceback" is the error, none of that is supposed to be there

Comment: @Hastur no the is no the sentex is fine

Comment: The end of python error mesage should look like `raise ValueError, "path '%s' cannot be absolute" % pathname
ValueError: path '/etc/fail2ban' cannot be absolute`  - looks like few lines at the end of the message are missing in your question.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal thats all that showed up, there is nothing missing

Comment: This is most definitely a bug in python..

Comment: @varfirstName so what should i do?

Comment: Would you be willing to update to Python 3.5? This is most likely a bug exclusive to Py2.5

Comment: @varfirstName sure if i can

Comment: That *might* fix it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44638/discussion-between-var-firstname-and-thestarvinggeek).

Comment: Your error log is incomplete, it doesn't include the actual error message. Could you provide the full log, including `ImportError` or whatever error you're getting?

Comment: Also, have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432587/python-bug-importerror-no-module-named-weakrefset) on SO?

Comment: @dmitrygrigoryev the error maybe incomplete but that's all that was in the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @varfirstname we found out this problem was caused by several depenancies getting corrupted. After trying for several hours to repair and reinstall them we came to the conclusion that the os needed to be reinstalled